# host is not a recognized parameter in elasticsearch

Tags: search, laravel, elasticsearch, parameters

i have a project with laravel on my localhost and i want to config elasticsearch on it but when i config my host this error appear : "host is not recognized parameter in elasticsearch"

i try it in anyway like :

```
$params = array('hosts' => array('host'=>'localhost'));
```

or `$params = array('hosts' => array('host'=>'127.0.0.1','port'=>8080));`
and some other way

error have some info :

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        if (array_search($key, $whitelist) === false) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($key . ' is not a valid parameter');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` array is not supposed to be keyed itself - that's basically what the error message is saying: key `host` (and `port`) is not expected.

In your code, try without the `host` key, just like this:

```
$params = array('hosts' => array('localhost:8080'));
```

The default is `localhost:9200`. For further details, read the [official documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like matpop said, the "hosts"-array is not keyed itself. Here a example from the es-documentation.

```
$params = array(); 
$params['hosts'] = array (
    '192.168.1.1:9200',         // IP + Port
    '192.168.1.2',              // Just IP
    'mydomain.server.com:9201', // Domain + Port
    'mydomain2.server.com',     // Just Domain
    'https://localhost',        // SSL to localhost
    'https://192.168.1.3:9200'  // SSL to IP + Port );

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```